# Joining two files by a common column

Tags: text-processing

I have two files.
First one is,

```
a 0.1 c t 0.4
c 0.25 g a 0.1
d 0.567 c c 0.00004
q 0.76 f c 0.05
```

The second one is,

```
a hello
c goodbye
d morning
q hungry
```

I want to make a file as below

```
hello 0.1 c t 0.4
goodbye 0.25 g a 0.1
morning 0.567 c c 0.00004
hungry 0.76 f c 0.05
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

Since the file is sorted we can directly use `join` command

```
 join  Second First | cut -f2- -d' '

hello 0.1 c t 0.4
goodbye 0.25 g a 0.1
morning 0.567 c c 0.00004
hungry 0.76 f c 0.05
```

if not sorted, use the code below:

```
join  <(sort second) <(sort first) | cut -f2- -d' '
hello 0.1 c t 0.4
goodbye 0.25 g a 0.1
morning 0.567 c c 0.00004
hungry 0.76 f c 0.05
```

Comment: Or add `-o 1.2,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5` to the `join` arguments instead of needing the `cut`.

Answer (score 4):

It should be pretty straightforward with `awk` where you can process the second file to consume the first column only and then later use the first file to populate it.

```
awk 'FNR == NR { map[$1] = $2; next } ($1 in map) { $1 = map[$1] }1 ' second first
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `join` approach, using join's inbuilt capabilities:

```
$ join -o 2.2,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5  <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
hello 0.1 c t 0.4
goodbye 0.25 g a 0.1
morning 0.567 c c 0.00004
hungry 0.76 f c 0.05
```

The `-o` lets you specify the output format. Here we are telling `join` to use the second field of file 2 (`2.2`), then the first, second, third, fourth and fifth  fields of file 1 (`1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5`).

Answer (score 0):

Using Paste.

```
paste <(cut -d ' ' -f2- file2) <(cut -d ' ' -f2- file1)
```

Using the shell.

```
while IFS= read -r file2 <&3; do 
  IFS= read -r file1
  printf '%s %s\n' "${file2##* }" "${file1#* }"
done 3<file2 <file1
```

Caveats

- Both are unsorted and the shell is slow when it comes to large files/data.
- Paste does not have an indentation but a straight format.